# Embedded System Hangs

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

I am using TIOMAP/AM3517 based custom board which has ARM7 core + Linux 2.6.32 running on it.
Recently, I started observing an issue in which all the interfaces serial console, RNDIS/USB, Network stops responding (my type on keyboard connected to serial port/console port doesn't go through + no device is detected upon removal/insertion of USB sticks/BT dongle + Ethernet/network activities are stopped (can't login over ssh or access webPage that the system has.

I checked the power to the CPU and other power rails using DMM and it looks fine. 
There is no keyboard attached so MagicSysRq cannot be used while the issue happens.

I have watchdog on the system which rebooted the system, however to reproduce the issue and to get more information of the system's state, now i have disabled the watchdog. 
Finally, my system/linux is configured to reboot upon detecting softlockup which is not happening either. Also, I have enabled verbose debug options under kernel hacking but nothing seems to give any more information.

How do I debug the issue to identify the rot cause of it?

Comment: Use the JTAG interface to examine the processor state.  You'll need special hardware for this, but rather than guess what may be happening, this should give you greater visibility into the processor state.  It could be any number of things going wrong such as mismatched DRAM timings causing corrupted memory reads, faulty drivers etc.

Comment: Consider adding something to the kernel which periodically flashes an LED or toggles a GPIO every second or so, and then looking to see if that is still alive.

Comment: Hi, I ended up finding the hang task (while 1 loop) in a kernel module with the help of JTAG. I also enabled LED support but it didn't tell me which task got stuck. Thanks